# Only half of react router link is clickable

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to use `Routes` to change pages in a React app. Here is my App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import Notifications from "./Components/Notifications";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Router>
            <header className="appHeader">
                <Link to="/" className="logoLink">
                    <img className="logo"/>
                </Link>

                <div className="headerLinks">

                    <li>
                        <Link className="notificationsLink" to="/notifications"> Notifications </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link className="updatesLink" to="/updates"> Updates </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link className="searchLink" to="/search"> Search </Link>
                    </li>

                    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path="/notifications" component={Notifications} />
                    <Route path="/updates" component={Notifications} />
                    <Route path="/search" component={Notifications} />

                </div>
            </header>
        </Router>


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the css for the `logoLink`:

```
.logoLink {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  left: calc(50% - 27.5px);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 2.5px;
}
```

The link is 55px by 55px and all of it should be clickable. But only half of it (I would assume 27.5px) is clickable. Here are images showcasing this:

[Unclickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1j3i.png)

[Clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGhlN.png)

As you can see only the left half of the link is clickable. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you add `left` in css?

Comment: So it is positioned in the middle of the screen

Comment: Remove that left property and just set display: flex; width: 100%

Comment: Or simply text-align: center; if width: 100% would break your layout

Comment: text-align: center     does not center it on screen and width 100% would mean the whole screen is clickable

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that you should know  that you were wrong  is this:

```
<img className="logo"/>
```

img tags wants src attribute.

Comment: It needs a className too

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess You forgot about `Switch` also I made a working codeSandbox of your code cuz I think you might have not export default your components(like `Notificatios,Home,etc`), [here is the link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-smoke-29xy1?file=/src/App.js:0-1414) and here is the App.js code:

```
import "./App.css";
import Notifications from "./components/Notifications";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Updates from "./components/Updates";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <header className="appHeader">
          <Link to="/" className="logoLink">
            <img className="logo" src="#" alt="HomeLogo" />
          </Link>

          <div className="headerLinks">
            <li>
              <Link className="notificationsLink" to="/notifications">
                {" "}
                Notifications{" "}
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link className="updatesLink" to="/updates">
                {" "}
                Updates{" "}
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link className="searchLink" to="/search">
                {" "}
                Search{" "}
              </Link>
            </li>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/notifications" component={Notifications} />
              <Route path="/updates" component={Updates} />
              <Route path="/search" component={Notifications} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </header>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: They all. have export default. And the Switch didn't help :(

Comment: @maximum360 Did you get the chance to check the link I shared with you?

Comment: I did. I copied and pasted the code from there and still only half of it is clickable. Which is weird because in the link you shared the whole thing is clickable

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` rather than `left: calc(50% - 27.5px);`. Still don't know why `left: calc(50% - 27.5px);` doesn't work, but this is a solid workaround